# MongoDB. How to move a field from one subdocument to other in an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection like this.

```
{ "key_a": 1,
  "key_b": [
           {"name": "pepe"},
           {"name": "juan", "code": 12345},
           {"name": "luis", "code": 5678}
          ]
}
```

"key_b" is an array of documents. I want to find documents that contains "pepe" and "juan", anf then move "code" from "juan" to "pepe". The result will be:

```
{ "key_a": 1,
  "key_b": [
           {"name": "pepe", "code": 12345},
           {"name": "juan"},
           {"name": "luis", "code": 5678}
          ]
}
```

What is the best way to do it? I am using pymongo.

Comment: You can use an aggregation pipeline to move the a field's value to another, and then perform an update - this is using MongoDB version earlier than 4.2. With version 4.2, you can do an [aggregation update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#updateone-behavior-aggregation-pipeline) for this operation - this is going to be a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in 2 steps. It's not strictly moving the field rather than updating both documents.

In MongoDB you can use $unset to remove a field: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

```
findOneAndUpdate({ name: "juan"}, { $unset: { "code": "" }}, { upsert: true }).exec()
```

Then you could use e.g.

```
findOneAndUpdate({ name: "pepe"}, { "code": newValue }, { upsert: true}).exec()
```

(The examples are mongoose, Pymongo update syntax is here: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update, not sure about $unset in Pymongo)

Comment: This solution doesn't work or is incomplete. The first step deletes "code" and also the value. Therefore, newValue does not exists. I want to move the value from one document to other.

Comment: Hey Juan - AFAIK there's not really a neat way to actually move the value from one to the other. Since you want to remove the field, what you may want to do is first get the value from the doc with name: juan and store it in the 'newValue' variable (how you decide to store the temp variable is up to you)